# Putting a border around multiple views in constraint layout

Tags: android, xml

I have tried looking at other SOF posts but found nothing exactly like my question as they were either slightly different (like a dialog) or were the wrong kind of layout. To be clear, I am not wanting a dialog and I need to use Constraint Layout.

I have a Constraint Layout (background colour grey) with a ProgressBar, Textview and an ImageView. The ImageView is a drawable white box with rounded corners, as seen in the image below. [image]

The issue I am having is that the ImageView (white box with rounded corners) is hardcoded to be 200dp by 100dp. What I want to happen is the box to scale to the content in the TextView. For this, I would guess I would need to change the width of the ImageView to `wrap_content`, but this does not show the box at all.

As an example, I would expect the box to be thin if the string in the TextView was short, and wide if the string in the TextView was long.

The code is below. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#989898">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/rounded_box" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Long string as textview"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: "For this, I would guess I would need to change the width of the ImageView to wrap_content" -- no, set it to be `0dp` and anchor it to the `TextView` instead of `parent`. Have the `TextView` be anchored to `parent`.

Comment: Perfect. That's solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you have to position the textView and the progress bar then you should position the imageView relative to TextView and ProgressBar , this is an example.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#989898"
    >

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:background="@color/white"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/textView"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/progressBar"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/textView"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/textView"
      />

  <ProgressBar
      android:id="@+id/progressBar"
      style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
      android:paddingTop="10dp"
      android:indeterminateTint="@color/red"
      />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      android:text="Long string as textview"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      android:padding="8dp"
      />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```